# Excel comments convert to access 2013

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a huge data on Excel file,

I know how to convert this data to Access database but i have some problem.

Some field on this data have comment if there any way to convert this comment to access 2013 or any another database.

And some field is coloring if there any way to convert this color to make it another column.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585423/exporting-comments-from-excel or http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/765-excel-convert-comments-to-cells.html

Comment: thank you this help me but How can retrieve the background color of cell

Comment: This is not difficult to find, just use google or stackoverfolw search. For instance check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957154/problem-with-getting-excel-cell-background-colors-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

just for your information: 
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=excel+comment+to+access

and i found this as first result:
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/765-excel-convert-comments-to-cells.html

for your second question: AFAIK not possible. you have extract the colored values into a new column and transfer it to Access. since you know "How" to transfer i leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thank you this very help article but how can retrieve the background colr